# playstore galaxy tab 3 wifi not supported

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest

since 3 days, i trying to register my app android in the play store. But the galaxy tab 3 wifi that i used, is not supported, i think there is a problem in manifest.xml but i do not know where.

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.edl.main"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0.1">

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-feature
android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location.network"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
    android:required="false" />

<supports-screens 
            android:resizeable="true"
            android:smallScreens="false"
            android:normalScreens="false"
            android:largeScreens="true"
            android:xlargeScreens="true"
            android:anyDensity="true"/>
<application android:name="com.edl.edl.ManagerEDL" android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/edl" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar">
    <activity android:name="com.edl.main.MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.edl.main.PiecesParPiecesActivity" android:label="@string/title_activity_pieces_par_pieces" android:screenOrientation="landscape">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.edl.main.EtatLieuxActivity" android:label="@string/title_activity_etat_lieux" android:screenOrientation="landscape">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.edl.main.EditionSignatureActivity" android:label="@string/title_activity_edition_signature" android:screenOrientation="landscape">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.edl.main.LieuxLouesActivity" android:label="@string/title_activity_lieux_loues" android:screenOrientation="landscape">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.edl.main.EditionSignatureSignedActivity" android:label="@string/title_activity_edition_signature_signed" android:screenOrientation="landscape">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.edl.main.RemiseCleActivity" android:label="@string/title_activity_remise_cle" android:screenOrientation="landscape">
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Thank's for your response.